# Second Monitor does not detect on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS but detects on Windows 8.1

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, dvi

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS on my secondary partition on my Solid State Drive. I noticed that when I went into System Settings --> Displays --> Detect Displays, my system is not detecting the second Acer monitor I have set up.

Other details that my be relevant is that I have a Nvidia GTX 750 TI and the Dell monitor is connected to the video card via DVI and the Acer monitor that is not detecting is connected to the video card through HDMI cable cord.

Please let me know if there is anything I can do to trouble shoot this. I'm sure it is not a hardware issue because the dual monitor set up works on my windows 8.1 OS partition. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

You could try making this the main video card in BIOS.

> the Acer monitor that is not detecting is connected to the video card through HDMI cable cord

It might make it detectable and hopefully the other monitor connected to the other card will work too. There is no harm in giving it a shot because if nothing loads, then you can always just switch it back to how it was before.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if your video card driver is installed correctly, by going to system settings, updates, additional drivers.
2. Run Nvidia settings, when GUI opens check on the Nvidia gui how many monitors are detected, press on detect displays from within the gui and see if second display is detected.
   If that don't work out,  check for driver or Linux software that can detect HDMI.

Comment: There is no NVIDIA GUI if he is using the open source drivers (which is what I recommend using).